# Why use /app/lib instead of /lib in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

In the sidekiq documentation, there is [this quote](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#autoloading) about preferring to use `/app/lib` instead of `/lib` in Rails projects related to autoloading errors:

> A lib/ directory will only cause pain. Move the code to app/lib/ and make sure the code inside follows the class/filename conventions.

Additionally, there is also:

> Don't configure extra paths in autoload_paths or eager_load_paths. That's a hack; follow the conventions! Any directory underneath app/ may contain Ruby code, you don't need to explicitly configure anything.

My questions are:

Is there any truth to these statements that using `/app/lib` is better than `/lib`?

Is this only helpful for autoloading Rails-related objects (such as AR models, controllers, jobs, etc)? Or will it also help POROs?

Is there only a specific context in which these comments make sense?

Comment: I would argue that not using autoloading is one of the reasons to put external classes into the `lib` folder. I wouldn't try to make autoloading working with the `lib` folder. I would always use an explicit `require` to load features from the `lib` folder.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In my experience `app/lib` is easier to use. You can literally stick in something like `Class MathFunction` and use it elsewhere (e.g. controllers or modules) with `MathFunction.sqrRoot`.

To use `/lib` you need to configure your Rails app with `autoload_paths`. `autoload_paths` also need some tweaking to work properly in [production](https://bigbinary.com/blog/rails-5-disables-autoloading-after-booting-the-app-in-production). Matz himself discourages `autoload` because it's in the process of [being deprecated](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5653).

The only time I've needed to use the `lib` directory is for making custom rake tasks. Otherwise I stick to `app/lib`.

Comment: Matz withdraw the proposal about autoload, please see end of your link

Comment: @Alirezamohagheghi is correct Matz withdrew his proposal. The answer is still relevant though typically I reserve `/lib` for custom rake tasks that are rails specific, and `app/lib` for code I want to reuse.